# Using isExpanded() with ng-bootstrap accordion

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am working Angular 10 and ng-bootstrap to create an accordion. The header on the panel header needs to display a "+" or "-" favicon based on if the panel is collapsed or expanded. I can not determine what the proper usage is the for the isExpanded method.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/api

```
<ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="true">
        <ngb-panel *ngFor="let item of items | keyvalue ; index as i; first as isFirst" id="ngb-panel-{{item.key}}" title="ngb-panel-{{item.key}}" type="dark">
            <ng-template ngbPanelHeader let-opened="{{isFirst ? 'opened' : ''}}">
                <div ngbPanelToggle class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between  bg-dark text-white">
                    <h5 class="m-0" ngbPanelToggle>
                        <button ngbPanelToggle class="text-white btn btn-link p-0">
                            <i class="fas fa-plus white plus-icon" *ngIf="isExpanded('ngb-panel-{{item.key}}')"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-minus white minus-icon" *ngIf="!isExpanded('ngb-panel-{{item.key}}')"></i>

                            <!-- Alternatively? -->
                            <i class="fas fa-plus white plus-icon {{ isExpanded ? 'd-none' : 'd-inline'}}"  ></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-minus white minus-icon {{ isExpanded ? 'd-inline' : 'd-none'}}"></i>-->
                            {{item.key}}
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
            </ng-template>
        </ngb-panel>
    </ngb-accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code is explained here :

Check this StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b5n7n1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

HTML file:

```
<div class="container">
  <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" id="accordion" (panelChange)="changeTitle($event, acc)">
    <ngb-panel title="{{ title }}">
      <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
        Content
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-panel>
  </ngb-accordion>
</div>
```

TS file:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  title: string = "TITLE WHEN NOT EXPANDED";

  changeTitle($event: NgbPanelChangeEvent, acc) {
    if (!acc.isExpanded($event.panelId)) {
      this.title = "TITLE WHEN EXPANDED";
    } else {
      this.title = "TITLE WHEN NOT EXPANDED";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion">
<ngb-panel id="panel1">
    <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
        <i class="icon" [ngClass]="acc.isExpanded('panel1')? 'icon-expand:'icon-collapse'"><span>Title</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template>
        Text Here
    <ng-template>
</ngb-panel></ngb-accordion>
```